# Why does my query not work using ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii1.x

I try to get `Article` models using this code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition("type = :type and name ILIKE :name";
$criteria->params = [
    ":type" => 1,
    ":name" => "art"
];
$articles = Articles::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

But it does not work I get:

> database error near ILIKE.

Comment: what database is this? Postgresql? mysql? (mysql doesn't have ILIKE)

Comment: @Jeff it's postgresql

Comment: What's the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use the wrong method of [CDbCriteria](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) for your query. Try to use addSearchCondition for ILIKE

```
$criteria->addSearchCondition("name", "art", true, "AND", "ILIKE");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%` wildcard character in searched value:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition("type = :type and name ILIKE :name");
$criteria->params = [
    ":type" => 1,
    ":name" => '%art%',
];
$articles = Articles::model()->findAll($criteria);
```